# Laravel 5.1: Unable to display $errors->first in template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have following html:

```
    <div class="form-group
      @if( $errors->has('question') )
        has-error has-feedback
      @endif
    ">
    <label for="question" class="col-md-4 control-label">Question</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="text" class="form-control c-square c-theme"
       id="Idquestion" name="question" value="{{Request::old('question')}}" placeholder="question text" >
   @if ($errors->has('question'))
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback">
   {!! $errors->first('question') !!}
     </span>
  @endif

  <?php echo 'PHP ERRORS: '. print_r ($errors->first('question')) ; ?>
   @if( $errors->has('question'))
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback">
     {{ $errors->first('question') }}
     </span>
  @endif
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="answer" class="col-md-4 control-label">Answer</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control c-square c-theme" id="Idanswer" name="answer" placeholder="input">
    </div>
 </div>
```

My problem is that, only $errors->all() is working. But $errors->has('question'), $errors->first('question') not working.

Following is my error showing html code:

```
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="c-center alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <ul>
            <li>Errors: {{  print_r ($errors)  }}</li>
            <li>Total Errors: {{  count($errors)  }}</li>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
            <li>Question Error: {{ $errors->first('question') }} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Html code for errors, shows me following:

```
  Errors: Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag Object ( [bags:protected] => Array ( [default] => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object ( [messages:protected] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => The question field is required. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => The answer field is required. ) ) [format:protected] => :message ) ) ) 1
Total Errors: 2
The question field is required.
The answer field is required.
Question Error:
```

Can some one guide me what I am doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

on your blade something link below.

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }} control-required">
            {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}<span class="mand_star"> *</span>
                {!! Form::text('title', isset($news->title) ? $news->title : \Input::old('title'), [
                    'class'       => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'News Title',
                    'required'    => 'required'
                ]) !!}
               <span class="error_span"> {{ $errors->first('title') }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

On your controller something like.

```
if ($validation->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('your route path')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
        }
```

it works for all individual input fields also fills old data in that field.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel Error Bag

Form name could be passed to the `MessageBag` of errors, allowing you to retrieve the error messages for a specific form.

Pass a name as the second argument to `withErrors`:

```
return redirect('viewName')->withErrors($validator, 'formName');
```

In the ***view***(blade) you can access the `MessageBag` using the name:

```
{{ $errors->formName->first('formFieldName') }}
```

Remember that you pass the name of the field inside ***first()***.
Check if you have form element with name ***"question"***

Refer docs [Laravel Error Bag](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages)

Hope this is helpful.